# Automatic resource group tagging with owner

Tags: function, azure, tags, service-principal

How can one create an automated way for when a resource group is created it is tagged with the owner's credentials?

Comment: you mean owner name? not credentials probably? i dont think you can do that with azure policy, but thats the only approach that might work

Comment: I meant with user mail like , author : (user.name@mail.com), I will try to make a powershell script that goes through the log activity and checks for "create resource group" activity and tag it with that, another example that i could not find out how to properly set up is this one (https://github.com/itaysk/azure-tagowner )

Comment: yeah, there is nothing built-in. you need a custom solution